# 2nd event Sally versus Fake Maple

Tags: bofuri

In the second event there is a part where Maple and Sally have to fight a fake version of each other. We end up getting the details of how Maple beats the fake Sally but the only information on how Sally beat the fake Maple is her showing her skill screen to Maple.

Is there any information on what skill Sally used to beat the fake Maple?

Answer (score 2):

I had originally thought she did it in a similar way to how Maple defeated fake Sally: by flooding the room with water and waiting for fake Maple to drown (Sally has Diving X, Maple has no Diving skill).

However, the skills that Sally had acquired during that battle seem to tell a different story:

- Cyclone Cutter;
- Combo Blade;
- Martial Arts I -> V;
- Wind Magic II -> III;
- Leap I -> III;

It is likely that some or even all of the above are red herrings. I'm not sure how to defeat a Maple in an enclosed space with the above. Suffocation probably wouldn't work with Wind Magic at such a low level, and the room isn't so tall that fall damage is a viable option.

Unless someone provides a viable alternative, I'll headcannon the drowning version of events.

Comment: Interesting information and maybe we will learn more as new events happen.